# Why is Math.sign([]) = 0, Math.sign([20]) = 1, and Math.sign([20, 30, 40]) = NaN?

Tags: javascript

As `Math.sign()` accepts a number parameter or number as a string as per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sign, why does it give the following results and how are the internal conversions taking place while giving these results?

```js
console.log(Math.sign([])); // 0

console.log(Math.sign([20])); // 1

console.log(Math.sign([20, 30, 40])) // NaN
```

Comment: Math.sing accepts integer or string

Comment: Type coercion. `[]` is converted to 0, `[20]` is converted to 20, `[20,30,40]` cannot be converted to a number.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It *expects* to be passed a number. If a non-primitive is passed to it, it attempts to convert that non-primitive to a number first.

When arrays are converted to numbers, their values are first joined by `,` to create a string, and then the interpreter tries to turn that string into a number. So with

```
Math.sign([]);
```

the empty array is converted to the empty string, which is then turned into a number - and `Number('')` is 0, hence the result is 0.

With `[20]`, this is joined into a string of `'20'`, which is then turned into the number `20`, whose sign is positive.

With `[20, 30, 40]`, this is joined into `'20,30,40'`, which cannot be turned into a number:

```js
console.log(Number('20,30,40'));
```

So the output is `NaN`.

Best to always do explicit type casting when you aren't 100% sure of what the result of implicit type coercion will be.

Comment: What conversion happens with Math.sign({}) and Math.sign({a: 5})?

Comment: When a plain object gets turned into a primitive, you get `[object Object]`, which can't be turned into a number - *unless* it also has a `valueOf` / `toString` property on it, *and* that property returns something which can be cast. Eg `Math.sign({ valueOf() { return 5 }})` evaluates to `1`